# Get font-size attribute from style property

Tags: jquery, font-size

I have a set of paragraph elements

```
<p style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:10.666666666666666; margin:0 0 0 0;">
<p style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:10.666666666666666; margin:0 0 0 0;">
<p style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:10.666666666666666; margin:0 0 0 0;">
<p style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:10.666666666666666; margin:0 0 0 0;">
```

I have to write `px` after font size degree. I am unable to use my current code

```
loop
$(this).css("font-size")
```

I can't use this because it shows me the font size of the parent `div`

Comment: browser will ignore the font-size if there is no unit(px, pt, etc) following it.

Comment: Yes, Parthik Gosar. That is the main problem. I need to write px to get correct font-size.

Answer (score 3):

There are two obvious approaches, the first looks at the `style` attribute searching for the numbers following the `font-size:` string and replaces that string with itself, though adding `px` to it:

```
$('p').attr('style',function(i,s){
    return s.replace(/font-size:\s*(\d+.{0,1}\d*)/, function(a){
        return a + 'px';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wu8dj/2/).

The second alternative is much the same, albeit it directly uses the inline `css()` method to set the `font-size` by finding the string `font-size:`, and the following numbers, then removing the `font-size:` string (so setting the `font-size` property to the numbers following that string and adding 'px' to it:

```
$('p').css('font-size',function(){
    var s = $(this).attr('style').match(/(?:font-size:)s*(\d+.{0,1}\d*)/)[0].replace(/font-size:/,'');
    return s + 'px';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wu8dj/1/).

Comment: actually I've did smth similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will read the current value, append "px" to it, and re-assign it back.

```
$(parent).children('p').each(function(){
    $(this).css("font-size", $(this).css("font-size") + "px");
});
```

Comment: it's no correct,  because it shows me the font-size of the parent div.

Comment: parent must be the element that contains these p tags. Why don't you just print the 'px' in whatever script is putting in the numbers?