# How to get element font-size inline style when there is more than 1 font-size css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the font-size value of elements style, but due to Important css I can't get the inline one.

[image: Style image]

How can I get inline font-size value?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get font-size attribute from style property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707836/get-font-size-attribute-from-style-property)

Comment: p.s. the very using of Important indicates of a lack of knowledge of  how to use css properly. always try find the correct order or making a stronger selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How abaout reading it manually from style tag:

```
var fontSize = $('.link-item').attr('style').match(/font-size:\s*(.*?);/)[1];
```